# MySql Inner join Order

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a Menu Module and facing an issue while retrieving Menu with respect to order.

[Kindly check the fiddle for reference.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35c32/2)

Here in Database: PARENTID denoted wether it is a parent or not.
If PARENTID=0, it is parent menu, else it is submenu.

PARENTLEVEL - Is the order of Level 1,2,3,4,5,6..

When I run the Query, I am able to get the menu in order:

> SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `publish`='1' and parentid='0' order by `menuorder` ASC

But when I want to order the Sub Menus I am not able to order them:

> SELECT * FROM category c inner join category b on c.parentid = b.parentid where c.publish='1' and c.parentid!='0'

I tried:

> SELECT * FROM category p LEFT JOIN category c ON 
>   c.parentid=p.parentid WHERE p.publish=1   order by
>   p.PARENTID,c.MENUORDER ;

What I am trying is:

I want the result in such an order:

```
    1.Home
    2.Settings
          Set Period
          User Type
          Roles
          Region
   .....etc
```

So, I can get the menu order in place. Can some one help me to order the menu/submenu under main menu?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, here the [edited version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35c32/38):

```
SELECT p.menuname pmen,c.menuname cmen,
 COALESCE(c.menutype,p.menutype) menutype,
 COALESCE(c.link,p.link) link,
 COALESCE(c.accessgroup,p.accessgroup) accessgroup
FROM category p 
LEFT JOIN category c ON  c.parentid=p.id AND c.publish=1 
WHERE p.publish=1 and p.parentid='0'  
ORDER BY p.menuorder,c.menuorder
```

Results:

```
|            PMEN |                    CMEN | MENUTYPE |     LINK | ACCESSGROUP |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|            Home |                  (null) | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|        Settings |              Set Period | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|        Settings |               User Type | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|        Settings |                   Roles | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|        Settings |                  Region | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|        Settings |                District | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|        Settings |                   State | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|        Settings |                    City | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|  Master Screens |            Product Type | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|  Master Screens |      Beneficiary Master | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|  Master Screens |        Component Master | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|  Master Screens |           Sub-Component | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|  Master Screens |              LOT Master | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|  Master Screens |           Tender Master | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|  Master Screens |         PDI Task Master | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
| User Management |                    User | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
| User Management |                    RBAC | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
| TPI Task Master |                  (null) | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|    Transaction  |              Work Order | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|    Transaction  |                  Vendor | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|    Transaction  |          PDI Inspection | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|    Transaction  |          TPI Inspection | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|    Transaction  |           DE Inspection | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|    Transaction  |           RM Inspection | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|    Transaction  | Install & Commissioning | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|    Transaction  |         Re-Installation | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|    Transaction  |          Bank Guarantee | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|    Transaction  |        Initiate Invoice | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|        Accounts |        Invoice Approval | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
|         Reports |                  (null) | leftmenu | home.php |           1 |
```